# What does -> means in Java

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am just looking to get an understanding on what the symbol '->' means. I wrote a simple method and closed that IDE session. When I returned back to continue my work, it looked as follows.

[image]

When I clicked on the method, it reverted back to how I initially wrote it as follows:

[image]

My Question is, is this a new syntax for Java 8.0 or did the IDE automatically did some kind of information collapse?

Comment: why not add code as `code`?

Comment: @Robert I believe this is about the code folding mechanism in recent versions of IntelliJ.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is either Java's 8 [Lambda Expressions](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html), but since I see the `(view) ->` grayed out a bit, it is probably folded by your IDE. Check: `Settings`, `Editor`, `Code Folding` and then uncheck `"Closures" (anonymous classes implementing a single method)`.

### EDIT

Yes, I checked IntelliJ 13. I have JDK 7 installed (I don't have v8 on my system), and checking `Settings`, `Editor`, `Code Folding` and then uncheck `"Closures" (anonymous classes implementing a single method)` makes them look exactly like the picture in the original question.

Comment: I think it is a feature of the android studio (based on IntelliJ), which has this feature.

Comment: It's been there in IntelliJ for a while, I think. I disabled it some time ago (since v10 or v11 I guess).