# what does the "->" means in java

Tags: java

I found this operator sign in java source code  here is all the code

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
 *
 */
package java.util.function;

/**
 * Represents an operation on a single operand that produces a result of the
 * same type as its operand.  This is a specialization of {@code Function} for
 * the case where the operand and result are of the same type.
 *
 * <p>This is a <a href="package-summary.html">functional interface</a>
 * whose functional method is {@link #apply(Object)}.
 *
 * @param <T> the type of the operand and result of the operator
 *
 * @see Function
 * @since 1.8
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface UnaryOperator<T> extends Function<T, T> {

    /**
     * Returns a unary operator that always returns its input argument.
     *
     * @param <T> the type of the input and output of the operator
     * @return a unary operator that always returns its input argument
     */
    static <T> UnaryOperator<T> identity() {
        return t -> t;
    }
}
```

I have googled  and  search in stackoverflow  but find nothing ,I want to know what is the sign **->** means

> I found this  [What does -> means in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254550/what-does-means-in-java), but I doestn`t fit me

--------------------Update-----------------------

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode)
```

Comment: which version of java you are using?

Comment: If it is jdk8 then it's related to lambda which was introduced in jdk8

Comment: `->` means a lambda expression where the part left of `->` are the arguments and the part right of `->` is the expression. `t -> t` means a function which uses `t` to return `t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see there is a Lambda expression, a new feature that was added in Java 8.

There is too much to say about lambdas to put it all here,  but in short it's a very concise way to add an anonymous class containing only a single method.

The method you mention there is functionally equivalent to:

```
static <T> UnaryOperator<T> identity() {
    return new UnaryOperator<T>{
       public T apply(T parameter){
         return parameter;
       }
    }
}
```

The full tutorial is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 1):

General syntax is,

> parameter -> expression body

Using lambda expression, you can refer to final variable or effectively final variable (which is assigned only once).

eg:

```
public class lambdatest{

   final static String firstmsg= "Hello! ";

   public static void main(String args[]){
      GreetingService greetService1 = message -> System.out.println(firstmsg+ message);
      greetService1.sayMessage("am here");
   }

   interface GreetingService {
      void sayMessage(String message);
   }
}
```

> output: Hello!amhere

Comment: This is hardly describing lambdas; and the use of final veriables is hardly the describing characteristic.